# When to Use a Numpy Array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, memory

When should I use a Python Numpy array?

I understand that Numpy is based in C and optimizes memory usage. However, I have never used a Numpy array in my production code. Am I overlooking a way to improve my code?

I have read several articles and referenced old class notes. But I am still not sure when I should opt for using Numpy arrays over a Pandas data frame.

Comment: There's an important distinction between using numpy in place of python lists, and using 'raw' numpy arrays instead of pandas structures which are themselves built on numpy.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually pandas is built base on Numpy. I use numpy when I have to deal with some linear algebra, matrices, vectorization problems, or to express N-dimentional objects (Dataframe express data in 1D or 2D as a table) I just use pandas when I have to deal with structure or categorical data.

Comment: One thing to note is that Pandas does support Series backed by arrays that are not Numpy arrays. It's not the default yet, but Arrow is used for several new dtypes, such as nullable integers and strings.